# How can I create a simple api to test my mobile app without having to code the api out on a server?

Tags: android, ios, api, testing, mocking

I am making an android and iOS app that is going to interact with a server using an api that returns appropriate json responses. Someone else on my team is doing the server side work. I don't want to bother/wait for her to finish the server implementation.

Is there a website out there that will help me create a test api so that whenever I call it, it will return a predefined Json response?

Example: if the website is called `api.com` and so if I create an account and call `GET api.com/my_account/get_key` it returns `{"key": "fgjllpoiunvxaqw"}`. I will hardcode the response on the website of course.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why the downvotes? Wrong tags? Not appropriate for stack overflow?

Comment: That's democratic process for you. =) This seems like a valid question to me; I was wondering the reason for the downvotes as well. It's a bit convoluted, but beginner coders may land here and learn about mocking. In any case, I upvoted.

Comment: @Nikunj I downvoted this because it's not an appropriate question. You're asking for others to do the work of finding an existing solution to... do your work for you. Your question is rather opened ended, and also [asks for a list of recommendations, which doesn't mesh with the way SE works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad). I sincerely hope nobody ever downvotes for incorrect tags, since those can be easily edited.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Thanks for the explanation. I did try to find such a solution myself before I posted. Couldn't come across a tool that was simple enough and wanted to tap on the experience of other front-end engineers on this forum. Will post on other forums for such advice in the future. Any idea where I can go for such "shopping-list" advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are **just reading data** from the server (e.g. making only /GET requests) you can put some .json files on server and just read them from your app.

For example, for get_key, you could call `GET yourwebsite.com/get_key.json` and parse the data. This way you can simulate how your app works with network delays, which is very useful to start adding loaders and error handling UI.

If you need to POST, I usually have a PHP script to write to a file on the server, to check later what it's being posted:

```
<?php
   file_put_contents('testPostUserData.txt', file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>
```

If you require **more dynamic interaction** (GET and POST data, retrieve some data for a specific user) then you can use some of the services available for free like [Backendless](https://backendless.com), [Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com/), [StackMob](https://stackmob.com/), or [Parse](https://parse.com/).

Finally, I usually have a preprocessor #define to alternate between fake API and real API

```
#ifdef FAKE_API
static NSString * path requestBaseURL = @"http://yourwebsite.com";
#else
static NSString * const requestBaseURL = @"http://realwebserver.com";
#endif
```

Comment: This is cool. Thanks! The list of websites is really useful too!

Answer (score 1):

That would be very simple to implement - what you need is a mock API. There's several around, like [**JMockit**](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/) and [**Mockito**](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

[**Mocking**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) is an integral part of software design and testing.

Comment: Thanks onosendai! I couldn't find the right words to put it and a mock api is exactly what I needed. I'll check the links out.

Answer (score 1):

Although this solution requires you to code a little, I think it may be good enough for some. 
While I was waiting for a response, I wrote a mock api using [BottlePy](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) and it was ridiculously easy for a new python developer like me.

Step 1: `easy_install bottle` or `pip install bottle`
Step 2: create your API as such:

```
from bottle import route, run
import json

@route('/login', method='POST')
def login():
    if request.POST.get('username') == 'a' and request.POST.get('password') == 'b':
        return json.dumps({'status': 'success'})
    else:
        return json.dumps({'status': 'fail'})

run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True)
# THATS IT!!!!
```

Step 3: Run the file using your console `python name_of_file.py` 
Step 4: DONE, your api is up. Test using `POST localhost:8080/login` in this case

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a really good website to do this: [Apiary](http://apiary.io/). Does exactly what I needed, plus a few other awesome things like creating documentation, providing collaboration tools, etc.